# Effect of changing sampling rate of an audio signal

Tags: audio-processing, resampling

What will happen when sampling rate of an audio signal is changed? Does it changes signals duration or signals total sample or both?

Answer (score 3):

If you treat the samples of a 48kHz sampled audio signal as if it was sampled at 16kHz and play it out of your D/A converter, then it will play back at 1/3 the speed, at 1/3 the pitch and at 3x the original duration.

If you use a samplerate converter to convert it to a 16kHz samplerate, then it will playback at 16kHz like the original, besides a lowpass filter at 8kHz.

Comment: Thanks for you response. So you are saying that total time and total sample will remain same or not that depends on how I am implementing the algorithm ,there is no universal rule?

Answer (score 2):

If you resample the clip to another sampling rate, e.g. from 96 kHz to 48 kHz, the duration in time is identical, because you both halve the number of samples and you also halve the rate of playing them back, or in other words, doubling the duration of each sample.

If you simply keep the original amount of samples and simply change the rate they are played back, then halving the playback rate takes twice as long to play the samples.